# C++ to MIPS assembly

Tags: c++, arrays, assembly, mips

if i transfer this code to mips.

```
int arr[3];

cin>>arr[0];

cin>>arr[1];

arr[1]+=arr[0];

cin>>arr[2];

arr[2]+=arr[1];
```

if i have value of arr[0] in $t0 ,arr[1] in $t1 and address of the arr in $s0.

in this line

```
arr[1]+=arr[0];
```

what i should do from this ?
use $t1 and $t0 direct like this

```
add $t1,$t1,$t0
```

or i should get the value again from the memory in a registers and do the add instruction like this:

```
lw $s1,($S0)

lw $s2,4($S0)

add $s2,$s2,$s1
```

what the compiler do ?

Comment: > what the compiler do ?  
check ur self

Comment: What the compiler does depends on other factors as well - such as optimization. If you compute a sum like `arr[1]+=arr[0]` but then do nothing with the result, the compiler can treat this as dead code and chose to not translate it at all. The same holds true for the compiler's decision to use registers and/or load the data from memory.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to get the values from the addresses again if you have properly loaded the values into `$t0` and `$t1`.

Compilers are very complex and what a compiler produces depends on many things, like optimization as Tilo mentioned. The best way to see is to compile it yourself and look at the code produced.